# How do I get the cookies from Apache HttpClient 4.x?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

How do I get the cookies from an existing object of type HttpClient? 
I'm using HttpClient version 4.3.3 which has no method httpClient.getCookieStore() anymore.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("/"), context);
try {
    CookieStore cookieStore = context.getCookieStore();
    List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Comment: I hoped it is possible to get the the CookieStore of the HttpClient without creating an own HttpClientContext like in version 3.

Comment: @eztam: Why is that? HttpClient always needs an execution context, so if it is not given explicitly one will be created behind the scene.

Comment: @ok2c because it causes a @#$@#$@#$ pain in the backside in certain perfectly normal scenarios

Comment: @YannickMenager What exactly cases the said pain in one's backside? Execution context?

Answer (score 0):

version 4.5.2
You can use this code:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = ((CookieStore)localContext.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE)).getCookies();
```